# In freeradius, is there a way to refer to LDAP attributes in post-auth section?

Tags: ldap, vpn, freeradius

We're using PEAP with mschapv2 using ntlm command line. We want to assign users ip's from LDAP

After we get a reply back from ActiveDirectory, we're doing an authorization check by binding to LDAP and looking at their groups:

```
  post-auth {
    if (network-auth-LDAP-Group == "xxxcompany-vpn") {
        noop
    } else {
        reject
    }
    Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
      attr_filter.access_reject
    }
  }
```

We'd like to pull `10.1.2.3` from an LDAP Attribute. We tried doing what the documentation says by putting this in the LDAP config:

```
update {
   reply:Framed-IP-Address := 'radiusFramedIPAddress'
}
```

In LDAP, we imported the schema and set `radiusFramedIPAddress` on the user to 10.1.2.3

However, we can't see the Framed-IP-Address value being updated in the log.

We'd like to set `Framed-Ip-Address` on the reply:

```
  post-auth {
    if (network-auth-LDAP-Group == "xxxcompany-vpn") {
       update reply {
         Framed-Ip-Address := 10.1.2.3
       }
    } else {
        reject
    }
    Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
      attr_filter.access_reject
    }
  }
```

That works however ^ Is there a way to refer to LDAP attributes in the post-auth section? Something like this?

```
  post-auth {
    if (network-auth-LDAP-Group == "xxxcompany-vpn") {
       update reply {
         Framed-Ip-Address := %{ldap:'radiusFramedIpAddress'}
       }
    } else {
        reject
    }
    Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
      attr_filter.access_reject
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This took way more brainpower than necessary, however, we figured out a way to do it:

```
  post-auth {
    if (network-auth-LDAP-Group == "xxxcompany-vpn") {
      update control {
        &Tmp-radiusFramedIPAddress := "%{%{network-auth:ldap:///ou=people,dc=division,dc=company,dc=com?radiusFramedIPAddress?one?(uid=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})}:-0.0.0.0}"
      }
      if (&control:Tmp-radiusFramedIPAddress != "0.0.0.0") {
        update reply {
          Framed-IP-Address := "%{control:Tmp-radiusFramedIPAddress}"
          MS-Primary-DNS-Server := 10.1.1.1
        }
        updated
      } else {
        noop
      }
    } else {
      reject
    }
    Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
      attr_filter.access_reject
    }
  }
```

Essentially, if you're a member of the correct LDAP group, attempt to look up the IP in the `radiusFramedIPAddress` attribute on the user. If it's found, it'll return the ip address and put it into the radius framed address which StrongSwan will use. If the user doesn't have an IP assigned in LDAP, it `noop`s out and the user will get an address from the pool.

I hope this helps someone!